# mvn gcloud:run Hangs

Tags: google-app-engine, maven-3, google-cloud-platform

I have a Google App Engine application which I'm trying to test locally.  Whenever I run the following command:

mvn gcloud:run

The application never fully starts up.  I have the following output written to my console:

```
mvn gcloud:run
[INFO] Scanning for projects...
[INFO]                                                                         
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Building Wildstar Service Desk 88
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] 
[INFO] >>> gcloud-maven-plugin:2.0.9.95.v20160203:run (default-cli) > package @ servicedesk >>>
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:resources (default-resources) @ servicedesk ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] Copying 0 resource
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:compile (default-compile) @ servicedesk ---
[INFO] Nothing to compile - all classes are up to date
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-resources-plugin:2.6:testResources (default-testResources) @ servicedesk ---
[INFO] Using 'UTF-8' encoding to copy filtered resources.
[INFO] skip non existing resourceDirectory /Users/derekberube/Documents/Programming/Java/Wildstar ServiceDesk/src/test/resources
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-compiler-plugin:3.3:testCompile (default-testCompile) @ servicedesk ---
[INFO] No sources to compile
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-surefire-plugin:2.12.4:test (default-test) @ servicedesk ---
[INFO] No tests to run.
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- maven-war-plugin:2.6:war (default-war) @ servicedesk ---
[INFO] Packaging webapp
[INFO] Assembling webapp [servicedesk] in [/Users/derekberube/Documents/Programming/Java/Wildstar ServiceDesk/target/servicedesk-88]
[INFO] Processing war project
[INFO] Copying webapp resources [/Users/derekberube/Documents/Programming/Java/Wildstar ServiceDesk/src/main/webapp]
[INFO] Webapp assembled in [26 msecs]
[INFO] Building war: /Users/derekberube/Documents/Programming/Java/Wildstar ServiceDesk/target/servicedesk-88.war
[INFO] 
[INFO] <<< gcloud-maven-plugin:2.0.9.95.v20160203:run (default-cli) < package @ servicedesk <<<
[INFO] 
[INFO] --- gcloud-maven-plugin:2.0.9.95.v20160203:run (default-cli) @ servicedesk ---
```

The following is the content of the log file generated by the gcloud process.

```
derekberube$ cat 22.54.23.587718.log
2016-03-07 22:54:23,593 DEBUG    root            Loaded Command Group: ['gcloud', 'info']
2016-03-07 22:54:23,594 DEBUG    root            Running gcloud.info with Namespace(__calliope_internal_deepest_parser=ArgumentParser(prog='gcloud.info', usage=None, description='This command displays information about the current gcloud environment.', version=None, formatter_class=<class 'argparse.HelpFormatter'>, conflict_handler='error', add_help=False), account=None, authority_selector=None, authorization_token_file=None, cmd_func=<bound method Command.Run of <googlecloudsdk.calliope.backend.Command object at 0x10cd2a590>>, command_path=['gcloud', 'info'], configuration=None, credential_file_override=None, document=None, format=None, h=None, help=None, http_timeout=None, log_http=None, project=None, quiet=None, show_log=False, trace_email=None, trace_log=False, trace_token=None, user_output_enabled=None, verbosity=None, version=None).
2016-03-07 22:54:23,687 INFO     root            Explict Display.
2016-03-07 22:54:23,687 INFO     ___FILE_ONLY___ Google Cloud SDK [99.0.0]

Platform: [Mac OS X, x86_64]
Python Version: [2.7.10 (default, Oct 23 2015, 19:19:21)  [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)]]
Python Location: [/usr/bin/python]
Site Packages: [Disabled]

Installation Root: [/Users/derekberube/google-cloud-sdk]
Installed Components:
  core: [2016.02.26]
  app-engine-python: [1.9.33]
  core-nix: [2016.02.05]
  pubsub-emulator: [2016.02.22]
  kubectl: []
  app-engine-java: [1.9.32]
  gcloud: []
  gsutil-nix: [4.15]
  app-engine-python-extras: [1.9.21]
  beta: [2016.01.12]
  gsutil: [4.17]
  bq: [2.0.18]
  alpha: [2016.01.12]
  gcd-emulator: [v1beta3-1.0.0]
  bq-nix: [2.0.18]
  kubectl-darwin-x86_64: [1.1.7]
System PATH: [/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/Applications/appengine-java-sdk-1.9.32/bin:/Applications/Java Libraries/Metro/2.3.1//bin:/Users/derekberube/google-cloud-sdk/bin:/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.8.0.jdk/Contents/Home/bin:/usr/local/apache-maven/apache-maven-3.3.3/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/opt/X11/bin]
Cloud SDK on PATH: [True]

Installation Properties: [/Users/derekberube/google-cloud-sdk/properties]
User Config Directory: [/Users/derekberube/.config/gcloud]
User Properties: [/Users/derekberube/.config/gcloud/properties]

Account: [wildstarservicedesk-hrd@appspot.gserviceaccount.com]
Project: [wildstarservicedesk-hrd]

Current Properties:
  [core]
    project: [wildstarservicedesk-hrd]
    account: [wildstarservicedesk-hrd@appspot.gserviceaccount.com]
    disable_usage_reporting: [False]
  [app]
    suppress_change_warning: [true]

Logs Directory: [/Users/derekberube/.config/gcloud/logs]
Last Log File: [/Users/derekberube/.config/gcloud/logs/2016.03.07/21.02.55.937592.log]



2016-03-07 22:54:23,695 DEBUG    root            Metrics reporting process started.
```

The following is a copy of my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>88</version>
    <groupId>com.wildstartech</groupId>
    <artifactId>servicedesk</artifactId>
    <name>Wildstar Service Desk</name>
    <url>http://servicedesk.wildstartech.com/</url>
    <properties>
        <appengine.app.version>${project.version}</appengine.app.version>
        <appengine.target.version>1.9.32</appengine.target.version>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    <prerequisites>
        <maven>3.1.0</maven>
    </prerequisites>
    <build>
        <!-- for hot reload of the web application -->
        <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>org.eclipse.jetty</groupId>
              <artifactId>jetty-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>9.3.7.v20160115</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                <artifactId>versions-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.2</version>                
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>com.google.appengine</groupId>
                <artifactId>gcloud-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.0.9.95.v20160203</version>
                <configuration>
                    <log_level>debug</log_level>    
                    <quiet>false</quiet>                
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>  
    </build>    
</project>
```

The following is a tree structure of my project.

```
|____pom.xml
|____src
| |____main
| | |____java
| | |____resources
| | |____webapp
| | | |____index.html
| | | |____WEB-INF
| | | | |____appengine-web.xml
| | | | |____web.xml
```

The following is my appengine-web.xml configuration file.

```
<appengine-web-app xmlns="http://appengine.google.com/ns/1.0">
    <application>wildstarservicedesk-hrd</application>
    <beta-settings>
        <setting name="java_quickstart" value="true"/>
    </beta-settings>
    <inbound-services>
        <service>mail</service>
    </inbound-services>
    <sessions-enabled>true</sessions-enabled>
    <!-- Configure java.util.logging -->
    <system-properties>
        <property name="java.util.logging.config.file" 
                  value="WEB-INF/logging.properties" />
    </system-properties>
    <threadsafe>true</threadsafe>
    <version>88</version>
    <vm>true</vm>
</appengine-web-app>
```

The following is my web.xml file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee
                             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_1.xsd" version="3.1">
    <welcome-file-list>
        <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.xhtml</welcome-file>
        <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    </welcome-file-list>
</web-app>
```

And last, but not least, the following is the content of the index.html

```
<DOCTYPE html>
<html>
   <head>
      <title>Test JSP</title>
   </head>
   <body>
      <p>This is a test.</p>
   </body>
</html>
```

The following is the stack output.

```
jstack 5155
2016-03-07 23:58:29
Full thread dump Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.80-b11 mixed mode):

"Attach Listener" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff4a500b000 nid=0x3d0b waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Service Thread" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff4a281d800 nid=0x4e03 runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread1" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff4a1819000 nid=0x4c03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"C2 CompilerThread0" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff4a406a000 nid=0x4a03 waiting on condition [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Signal Dispatcher" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff4a4064800 nid=0x3e0f runnable [0x0000000000000000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE

"Finalizer" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff4a4041800 nid=0x3803 in Object.wait() [0x0000700000d3a000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007aeb20070> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:135)
    - locked <0x00000007aeb20070> (a java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue$Lock)
    at java.lang.ref.ReferenceQueue.remove(ReferenceQueue.java:151)
    at java.lang.ref.Finalizer$FinalizerThread.run(Finalizer.java:209)

"Reference Handler" daemon prio=5 tid=0x00007ff4a1813800 nid=0x3603 in Object.wait() [0x0000700000c37000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: WAITING (on object monitor)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Native Method)
    - waiting on <0x00000007aeb10278> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)
    at java.lang.Object.wait(Object.java:503)
    at java.lang.ref.Reference$ReferenceHandler.run(Reference.java:133)
    - locked <0x00000007aeb10278> (a java.lang.ref.Reference$Lock)

"main" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff4a4001000 nid=0x1703 runnable [0x0000700000218000]
   java.lang.Thread.State: RUNNABLE
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:152)
    at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(SocketInputStream.java:122)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.fill(BufferedInputStream.java:235)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(BufferedInputStream.java:275)
    at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:334)
    - locked <0x00000007abefec10> (a java.io.BufferedInputStream)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTPHeader(HttpClient.java:690)
    at sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.parseHTTP(HttpClient.java:633)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getInputStream(HttpURLConnection.java:1324)
    - locked <0x00000007abee63d0> (a sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection)
    at com.google.appengine.gcloudapp.GCloudAppRun.stopDevAppServer(GCloudAppRun.java:486)
    at com.google.appengine.gcloudapp.GCloudAppRun.execute(GCloudAppRun.java:287)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:134)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:80)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:128)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:307)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:193)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:106)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:862)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:286)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:197)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)

"VM Thread" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff4a4039800 nid=0x3403 runnable 

"GC task thread#0 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff4a400d000 nid=0x2403 runnable 

"GC task thread#1 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff4a400d800 nid=0x2603 runnable 

"GC task thread#2 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff4a180a800 nid=0x2803 runnable 

"GC task thread#3 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff4a400e800 nid=0x2a03 runnable 

"GC task thread#4 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff4a180f800 nid=0x2c03 runnable 

"GC task thread#5 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff4a1810800 nid=0x2e03 runnable 

"GC task thread#6 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff4a1811000 nid=0x3003 runnable 

"GC task thread#7 (ParallelGC)" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff4a400f000 nid=0x3203 runnable 

"VM Periodic Task Thread" prio=5 tid=0x00007ff4a281e800 nid=0x5003 waiting on condition 

JNI global references: 236
```

Answer (score 1):

From a terminal window, I ran the command `ps -eaf |grep java` and one of the processes listed in the output contained the word `(java)`.  This happens whenever the `ps` command is NOT able to read a value from the `CMD` column.

I used the `kill -eaf` command to terminate the thread running the `(java)` process.

After doing that, the `mvn gcloud:run` process continued execution.